# Delete button instead of a link

Tags: php, codeigniter, button

I want to delete something from my DB when the delete button is clicked.
So far I have a link to delete information from my DB, but I want to display a button instead of a link.

I don't understand how to implement a submit button in the following code.

```
<p>
    <?php echo anchor('del_controller/del/'. $id, 'Delete', array('onClick' =>   "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"));?>
</p>
```

Comment: FYI, you will be more likely to get answers to your questions if you mark some of your previouse questions as answered =/

Comment: @tan Fantastic!  that'll help you out in the long run =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the form_submit()-function instead:

```
<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!'); ?>
```

As read in the documentation:

> Similar to other functions, you can submit an associative array in the first parameter if you prefer to set your own attributes. The third parameter lets you add extra data to your form, like JavaScript.

So, getting the result you want you would probably have to write:

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => "submit",
    'value'       => "Delete",
    'onClick'     => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
);
echo form_submit($data);
```

The path to POST the form to is set when opening the form.

```
echo form_open('del_controller/del/'. $id);
```

Read more at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html